# problem with finish() :Android

Tags: android, user-interface, exit, toast

In an if statement, I have a finish() because I don't want the control to go any further. But, the app exits, but as I see from the logcat, the control goes beyond finish().

Maybe that's also the reason why a toast supposed to be displayed and some other GUI actions before finish() are not taking place?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

onPause and onDestroy will be called after finish

Comment: onPause and onDestroy get called only when they are overriden in the current activity.